# How to check file exist or not with php wget

Tags: php, curl, wget

one big trouble with checking my file exist or not where first i used curl but in my app its not working so,
like this

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
```

now i want to replace this with by wget and its working for my app i've checked on linux command prompt. so, please help me how to use wget with php to checking url existence.

and also how to get the response code from this. please help.

Comment: For checking the existance without testing the contents of the resource usually a "HEAD" request suffices. see CURLOPT_NOBODY in http://docs.php.net/function.curl-setopt

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your working shell line and get it's result using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Still, using curl is much better idea, than wget. What is the problem with your curl script?